# getting all possible combinations while staying under max constraint

Tags: python, combinations

```
  def pickSubs(self, subjects, maxWork, maxLottery):

    totWork = 0
    totLott = 0
    studentSubs = []
    for s in subjects:
        totWork += s.getWork()
        totLott += s.getLottery()

        if totLott <= maxLottery and totWork <= maxWork:
                studentSubs.append(s)

    return studentSubs
```

I am trying to use comparators  to decide best choices for a student based on different factors.

My issue is I want to append all possible objects 's' if the total work and lottery  values are under maxWork, maxLottery  but  I am not appending all possible combinations. 
I am just appending until I reach max constraint value

How can I get all possible combinations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/464864/139010

Comment: Do the getWork and getLottery methods return different values each time?

Comment: @chthoni yes I am parsing a txt file with many different values. So it is not just combinations but combinations while staying under both maxWork and maxLottery

Comment: Another question: are these things independent or dependent? In other words, is there a "work" associated with a "lottery" or are can one assign them as separate problems? I would imagine a good place to start would be to have a list of works and lotteries instead of reading them sequentially as you are now. Depending on how many of these things you have, it may also be better to use a MILP solver for this rather than enumerating all the possible combinations.

Comment: Basically each instance 's' is:Course,Value,Work,Lottery.  Work is an integer and Lottery is either 1 or 0 where 1 indicates the subject is a lottery and 0 means it is not. So both Work and Lottery values are relevant to whether the subject shall be taken by the student or not. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon do you have any good link on MILP, I am struggling to find any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your question as asked:

```
def pickSubs(self, subjects, maxWork, maxLottery):
    from itertools import chain, combinations

    validcombinations = []

    for comb in chain.from_iterable(combinations(subjects, n) 
                                    for n in range(1, len(subjects)+1):
        sumWork = sum(s.getWork() for s in comb)
        sumLottery = sum(s.getLottery() for s in comb)

        if sumWork <= maxWork and sumLottery <= maxLottery:
            validcombinations.append(comb)
    return validcombinations
```

But, be aware that this will typically go through an incredibly long list. If you are actually trying to find the "best" selection of subjects which satisfies these criteria, I really recommend you have a look at something like [PuLP](http://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/), where you can set this up as an integer problem using binary choice variables. I think how to do that would require you to ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me on this, I have an issue, the sumWork is returning only one value repeatedly so it never goes past the if statement.